# How to fix encoding problem with Spark JDBC?

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, jdbc

I have table in Oracle which has some records in Russian.

When I read this table with Spark JDBC, I receive dataframe with not correct values.

Do you have idea why it is happening and how to fix that?

```
// executes given query using jdbc
  def executeQuery(spark: SparkSession, configuration: Map[String, String], sql_statement: String): DataFrame
  = spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")
    .option("url", s"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//${configuration("address")}")
    .option("user", configuration("username"))
    .option("password", configuration("password"))
    .option("dbtable", s"(${sql_statement})")
    .option("fetchSize", configuration("fetch_size"))
    .load()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your jdbc connection you would need to set `.option("encoding", "UTF-8")` and `("characterEncoding", "UTF-8")` to ensure that we use UTF8 character set while reading the data. This should ensure that you are able to read the russian characters properly.

Comment: It does not work on JDBC